# Laravel Paginator getTotal returns null - Need total record count for all pages

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have implemented simple pagination using laravel. It works fine. However, I want to add total number of records and trying to use the method getTotal() but it returns null value.

```
$records = DB::table('tablename')
           ->where(condition)
           ....
           ....
           ->simplePaginate(10);
```

In the view, adding links works fine.

```
 {{$records->links();}}
```

When I use,

```
{{$records->getTotal();}}
```

it returns null.

If I use,

```
{{$records->count();}}
```

it returns the count of records for a given page.

Any insights please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `simplePaginate` works. From the docs:

> If you are only showing "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you have the option of using the simplePaginate method to perform a more efficient query. This is useful for larger datasets when you do not require the display of exact page numbers on your view.

The simple method is simple because it doesn't need to do the extra, inefficient-on-large-tables `count` query to obtain the total.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, what would be the best approach. Switching to paginate or to run the entire query once again to get the count.? The query joins close to 10 tables and conditional where clauses (on about 20 fields) to implement search functionality.

Comment: @Chandra Both approaches re-run the query, so I'd switch to paginate for simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

There is method total() in that pagination object. Just call that object. You will get total count.

ex: `$records->total();`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did was

```
$records = DB::table('tablename')
       ->where(condition)
       ....
       ....
       ->paginate(1);  //set as 1

$total = $records->getTotal();  //get total
```

Then returning it like this(I am using ajax that is why I return it as array):

```
return Response::JSON(array(
    'pagination'     => (string) $records->links('pagination::simple'),
    'total_records'  => $total
));
```